# Is it possible to find the intersect point

Tags: android, path

In Android, a path created by "quadTo" method. If I have the X coordinate value, is it possible to find the Y coordinate value?

As before, I had considered the "PathMeasure". But I failed to find the correct result.

does anyone can give some idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Path.quadTo()` creates a standard quadratic Bezier between the current point, approaching the first (x,y) argument and ending at the second (x,y) point. You should be able to generate the equation explicitly and solve for it. I think that, unfortunately, there is nothing in the API to do this calculation.

Note, however, that any particular quadratic Bezier curve may intersect the line `x = constant` anywhere from 0 to 3 times.